# Eclipse project linked resources by environment variable

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, environment

I'm having trouble setting up my Eclipse C++ project. I need to link in source from different directories here and there and in my environment the source I need actually moves sometimes (for example when i always want the latest version of a sub system currently located in a directory like `/aaa/bbb/v1.2.3/src`). I always know the location of the source I want through linux environment variables, like `$SYSTEM1_LATEST_ROOT`. Without this I need to update all my projects whenever i should pick the source from a new location.

I cannot find a way to include the environment variables in the paths for linked resources. Include directories work perfectly (these are defined in my `.cproject` file), for example (`.cproject`):

```
<option id="..." name="Include paths (-I)" superClass="gnu.cpp.compiler.option.include.paths" valueType="includePath">
    ...
    <listOptionValue builtIn="false" value="${SYSTEM1_LATEST_ROOT}/src"/>
    ...
</option>
```

For linked resources (defined in the .project file) I know I can use path variables but these are defined inside Eclipse only and I find no way to have them based on environment variables, but only to be relative to my own project location, which is not what I want to do.

In short, I want to link in source code from locations based on environment variables. The variable name is constant, but the actual location (known through the environment variable) of the source is not.

Working example with path relative to project. This is not what i want (.project):

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>System1_src</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>PARENT-6-PROJECT_LOC/src</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Non-working example of what i want to do (.project):

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>System1_src</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <locationURI>${SYSTEM1_LATEST_ROOT}/src</locationURI>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After waiting for a month i figure it's time I answer with my own findings..

First, the concept of path variables (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cpathvars.htm);

```
"Linked resource target paths can be either defined 
 as absolute paths, or relative to a path variable."
```

Two options; absolute paths or relative to path variable.

Specifically it says about path variables:

```
"Each project contain a pre-defined set of path 
 variables available for defining linked resources, 
 including ECLIPSE_HOME, PARENT_LOC, PROJECT_LOC and 
 WORKSPACE_LOC.

New path variables can be defined relative to 
existing path variables by using the ${VAR} syntax. 
For example, a path variable FOO can be defined 
relative to BAR by defining it to "${BAR}../foo"."
```

In other words, path variables are always relative to the project location in some way, using a liberal interpretation of the word project.

So the next option would be absolute path. An absolute path containing an environment variable would work!

```
"The linked resource target path can be changed by 
 selecting the Edit... button in the File > Properties > 
 Resource property page of the linked resource. "
```

Trying this it gets painfully obvious that only path variables are supported as part of the path to the linked resource. And we already know the definition of a path variable.

The answer is...

Eclipse does not contain this very basic feature.

**Anyone, please prove me wrong!**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings.  I'm currently going through a similar amount of pain with my eclipse-based IDE.  However, if you can use ${VAR}, then should yours have worked if you tried ${SYSTEM1_LATEST_ROOT}./src?

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd add my solution to the problem here so others might be able to benefit from it.

While not supported "by default", it turns out that Eclipse can use path variables.  The key here is to use its "Linked Resources" feature.  Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Linked Resources and add your path variables there.

[image]

Comment: I think this would answer my question only if the value of the `path variable` can contain an `environment variable`, for example `${FREESCALE}/KSDK_1.1.0`. The point is that i want the linked resource to be linked in based on environment variables set by some admin that controls my environment.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured that would be a problem.  Did you try using an env variable for the Value and find that it indeed does not work?

Comment: Yes, what makes it so annoying is that it works perfectly for include paths but not for linked resources. I don't exactly recognize your screenshot so i might have another go with a newer eclipse version, but it's been a while since i was messing with this. At the time it really felt like i had tested every possible way to edit the linkedResource xml.

Comment: @MartinG Any changes since? Are we still not able to use environent variables here?

Comment: This solution is not what was requested but it is still useful, as the environment variable need be copied to a single Eclipse path variable, then used in multiple places inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I got it to work.
I add a new folder to the project and I click on Advanced. This is the screen

[image]

I add the folder name (virtual name, to be linked to the real folder) and I use this environment variable:

```
${WORKSPACE_LOC}\my_path_to_the_external_src
```

Eclipse can resolve the trick.
Anyway another step is needed.

Click on the newly added folder -> properties and you have to uncheck the exclude from build:

[image]

At this point, the trick is working for me.

It is mandatory to have the environment variable all capital letters!

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean this works for environment variables and not just the WORKSPACE_LOC symbol?

Comment: No, sorry, maybe I've misunderstood the post. Only for eclipse-defined environment variable, it's not system variables :-(

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this thread but here is what works for me:

- Define a **workspace** scoped Path Variable e.g. `MYPATH_WS` and set this
- Define a **project** scoped Path Variable e.q. `MYPATH` and reference the workspace variable
- Import your linked resources relative to the **project** scoped variable.

Now when someone else takes your code, they can set their own **workspace** scoped variable `MYPATH_WS` and voila!

I also needed this to work in a GitHub CI and for this I had the build system patch the `.project` file at build time to replace the referenced `<value>$%7BMYPATH_WS%7D</value>` with a proper path to wherever the linked resources are in the CI environment e.g. to `<value>file:/d:/somewhere/else/resources</value>` (it's eclipse so a Windows build in my case!).